# How to display a select option based on SQL result - VB.net

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, vb.net

I have some sample data here...[Sample Data to query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZivt.png)

The SQL is as follows;

```
 "Select Person, Travel, WithWho FROM database
       where (Person like '" & txtSearch.Text & "' 
       or Travel like '" & txtSearch.Text & "'
       or WithWho like '" & txtSearch.Text & "')"
```

I am displaying the ways of travel in a **listbox** which is populating fine.
I am displaying the **WithWho** field in a **textbox** and this is where the problem is. It is populating the **textbox** with SARAH who is the first record in the database and ignoring **JOANNE**. This is in a WPF application. I was wondering does anyone know how I could provide an option to select which record to load or even to search through the records on the form.

Thanks for any help

[Sample code to display WithWho in textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvjsG.png)

Comment: Questions asking for advice are likely to solicit debate and so I have voted to close

Comment: This is open to SQL injection.

Comment: I´m not sure what you are really asking. You want to display all names with who the given person was travelling in a single textbox? If so: why?

Comment: This is just sample data to see what could be done with the real data. The person who will be searching will know which "person they want to travel with" therefore i want them to be able to select the correct person and then load all the data based on who they are travelling with

Comment: depending on WhoWith determines information loaded to other textboxes in the form. If there is only one person in WhoWith then the situation is fine as it will populate the WhoWith textbox correctly. When there are 2 owners only the first person is populated. I want to have it where the USER is shown the two or more results and has to click which result to load

Comment: So why don´t you show all users in a combobox instead of a textbox?

Comment: Need to see the code that gets the WithWho data from your query to your TextBox. It seems like you are only reading the first result rather than looping through all returned rows.

Comment: @AlexB. I do not need a combo box. I am asking how you provide the user with a choice of what they would like to view. Its more than 300'000+ records so i would rather provide a choice rather than loading all.

Comment: @Josh Please see image edit for sample of code on how i am displaying the WithWho to the textbox. Thanks for any help

Comment: "how you provide the user with a choice of what they would like to view". Sorry I don´t get your point. Which choice does the user have if you don´t give him a proper way to choose it, e.g. in a combobox. 
Btw...your code for populating the textbox misses a concatenation of the different WithWho names.

Comment: Do you want the user to enter manually a name in the textbox and then your UI will get updated with the relevant data?

Comment: @AlexB. by combobox do u mean this would appear say below a search textbox, they click the user and it loads them details? I will search a PERSON, it will populate a listbox with ways to TRAVEL, but in one textbox I want to show who they are travelling WITH. There will be a records, eg 2'500, with the same person, that will display ways to travel in a listbox, but the textbox is populating with the first WHOWITH person read from the database. If there was a way that i could search, check if there are a number of WHOWITH differences, show the user this and let them select the correct WHOWITH?

Comment: When they select this correct WHOWITH, it will populate say 30 different fields in the form with specific information in relation to the PERSON, TRAVEL and WHOWITH. I have no issues populating the fields, i just need a way to alert the user that there is a difference in the WHOWITH results. Say 300 records return, the WHOWITH field could have 299 with SARAH but 1 with JOANNE, if they click sarah it will be the same for all 299 fields of sarah, but if they pick JOANNE then fields will differ

Comment: @AlexB. no the only input from the user will be from the search textbox for this particular section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted will only display one name in the TextBox because it resets the *entire* value of the `Text` property, rather than *concatenating* additional names. You can fix this with the following:

```
txtPname.Text = ""
While reader.Read()
    countvalues += 1
    If reader("WithWho") Is DBNull.Value Then
        txtPname.Text &= Environment.NewLine & "Unknown"
    Else
        txtPname.Text &= Environment.NewLine & reader("WithWho")
    End If
End While
```

These results still won't be exactly what I think you want, but it's a start if you're set on the TextBox route. From your comments, however, I believe what you really want is a ListBox, populated like so:

```
lstPname.Items.Clear()
While reader.Read()
    Dim pName As String
    If reader("WithWho") Is DBNull.Value Then
        pName = "Unknown"
    Else
        pName = reader("WithWho")
    End If
    If Not lstPname.Items.Contains(pName) Then
        lstPname.Items.Add(pName)
    End If
End While
```

This will give the user a box where each name (including "Unknown", if applicable) will appear exactly once. Unlike a TextBox, they can then click the name and its row will immediately be highlighted. You can then code your other controls to respond to the `lstPname.SelectedIndexChanged` event to ascertain which person is selected and display the appropriate information.

Comment: cheers for that, I will get some time tomorrow morning looking at this and let you know how I get on. Thanks for your time, appreciate it